# Just how awful *is* Harry Potter's eyesight

Tags: harry-potter

> “Harry, your eyesight really is awful,” said Hermione, as she put on glasses *(Deathly Hallows, Chapter Four - "The Seven Potters")*

In-universe, do we know to what extent Harry Potter's eyesight was bad?

Obviously, we wouldn't have exact prescription [dioptre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioptre) numbers, but what I'm hoping for is some **canon or WoG example of Harry not able (vs able) to see something specific when not wearing glasses**.

Comment: Perfect example of a question that will never have any real-world usefulness - also known as a "who the hell cares" question ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor I think you forgot "(in my opinion)" ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor: Isn't writing a piece of fanfic where the eyesight is a plot point enough usefulness for an in-universe-fact to matter?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - yay. This is my new go-to excuse when anyone accuses me of "why is that a real question?". I'm writing a fanfic. Cross between Conan, Star Wars, Harry Potter, Percy Jackson, GPF, Honor Harrington, Dune and Rama.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After taking polyjuice potion, he sees with Goyle's (unaided) vision. His glasses "cloud" his eyes, suggesting that his vision (with glasses) must be at least 4-5 points off 20:20. Anything less and his vision would simply be distorted rather than actually blurry:

> *Then he realised that his glasses were clouding his eyes, because
>   Goyle obviously didn’t need them* - **HP: CoS**

He can't see well enough to distinguish that what he's looking at is a large dog, but he can see well enough to tell that it's an animal of some kind:

> *Harry set down his goblet and was about to turn back to his bed when
>   something caught his eye. An animal of some kind was prowling across
>   the silvery lawn.* - **HP: POA**

He can distinguish his location and make out his friends easily from across the room. If he squints, he can bring his vision to something approaching normality:

> *Everything was slightly blurred. Somebody had removed his glasses. He
>   was lying in the dark hospital wing. At the very end of the ward, he
>   could make out Madam Pomfrey with her back to him, bending over a bed.
>   Harry squinted. Ron’s red hair was visible beneath Madam Pomfrey’s
>   arm* - **HP: PoA**

Familiar people have "fuzzy outlines", again, suggestive of moderate myopia

> *He could see the fuzzy outlines of Mrs Weasley and Bill close by. Mrs
>   Weasley was on her feet. ‘That’s Fudge’s voice,’ she whispered. ‘And
>   that’s Minerva McGonagall’s, isn’t it? But what are they arguing
>   about?’* - **HP: GoF**

Room is blurry

> *Harry emerged from behind his towel; the changing room was blurred
>   because he was not wearing his glasses, but he could still tell that
>   everyone’s face was turned towards him.* - **HP:OotP**

He can't distinguish *individual* firework sparks

> *He got into bed, yawning. With his glasses off, the occasional
>   firework passing the window had become blurred, looking like sparkling
>   clouds, beautiful and mysterious against the black sky.* - **HP: OotP**

Comment: I don't know what impresses me more, that you found all these quotes or that JKR managed to keep such a minor detail pretty consistent throughout the series.

Comment: @kevin - She's usually pretty consistent about anything not involving maths. That being said, I stand by my assertion that she didn't write the books. They were clearly ghost-written for her by a team working for the studio.

Answer (score -2):

Which means Harry is near-sighted. Things far away are blurs. How near-sighted? Probably 20:100 That means what is normally seen clearly at 100 feet needs to be at 20 for him. It might be closer to 20:200 (legally blind) because if Mrs. Weasley is close enough to whisper to him, she should NOT be blurred less than ten feet away at 20:100

Comment: Do you have any evidence for any of this that you could [edit] in?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - This doesn't really feel like an answer. It feels more like an attempt to comment on my answer.

Comment: @Valorum it certainly reads as a comment but it can be argued it’s an answer still.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Oh, sure. Which is why I've not flagged it.

Comment: "Which means Harry is near-sighted."  This does not make sense as a response to anything in the question; it only makes sense in the context of a comment on Valorum's answer.  "Things far away are blurs."  Which things?  How far away?  Where are the quotes?  In Valorum's answer; it's pretty clear this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Is the 20:100 and 20:200 from an American sight test system?